# Oracle 'printf' equivalent

Tags: oracle, string, formatting, printf

Is there an equivalent or alternative to the following?

```
SELECT mix_type || ' (' || mix_num || ')' as description
  FROM acid_batch
 WHERE mix_num < 10
```

Does Oracle have something like printf style formatting?

```
SELECT printf("%s (%s)", mix_type, mix_num) as description,
  FROM acid_batch
 WHERE mix_num < 10
```

Comment: The syntax of (str_a || ' ' || str_b) or the above to surround a string with parentheses seems ugly (for code) and difficult to read.  It just seems like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: Another solution would be to write a pl/sql package that takes arguments, and formats things the way you want them.

Comment: Unfortunately PL/SQL does not (yet) support variable numbers and types of parameters for a function - the closest way would be to implement FUNCTION printf(t varchar2, v1 varchar2 := null, v2 varchar2 := null, v3 varchar2 := null, v4 varchar2 := null, v5 varchar2 := null) RETURN VARCHAR2 (add additional varchar2 parameters if you need them). Although I'd consider renaming it because the purpose of printf is to send the result to stdout, whereas here you're expecting it to simply return the resulting string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there are no built-in Oracle functions that apply a formatting string in this fashion.  Although it would be easy to write a custom function for this specific example, writing a PL/SQL-based implementation of printf would be challenging.

If you have a frequent need for this, perhaps you could write an Oracle function that wraps a Java call for a richer string handling environment.

Comment: Now this is an old answer, but do you know if this still is the case?

Answer (score 27):

The closest standard approximation to printf for Oracle I can think of is [utl_lms.format_message](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_lms.htm#ARPLS71194). However, it won't work in SQL statements, that is, this is ok:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(
    utl_lms.format_message('hello %s, the number is %d', 'world', 42)
  );
end;
/
```

but this gives a *ORA-00902: invalid datatype* error:

```
select utl_lms.format_message('hello %s, the number is %d', 'world', 42)
  from dual
```

Comment: The documentation says this is for error messages ("*UTL_LMS retrieves and formats error messages in different languages.*"). Do you know if there are any problems or restrictions with using it for normal strings? The documentation is quite sparse.

Comment: this is they way i do.. but all parmaters must be CHAR/VARCHAR.. ie  ``select utl_lms.format_message('hello %s, the number is %s', 'world', TO_CHAR(42) )
  from dual``

Comment: @ShoeLace Are you sure this works in pure SQL? When I run your statement in Oracle liveSQL I always get ORA-00902:
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/lagy8m7u3q7grc1brrq9zsdr6

Comment: @Pesse I belive it was accurate as of oracle 10.1, but may no longer be true.. I do not have an older version installed to confirm..

Comment: It doesn't work with `NUMERIC` or `NUMBER` only with PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a simple template engine named [ora_te (on GitHub)](https://github.com/blza/ora_te) for Oracle SQL / PLSQL.
With the help of it your goal can be achieved in the following ways:

Noneffective implementation with multiple parsings of template string:

```
with acid_batch as (
  select rownum as mix_type, rownum + 2 as mix_num 
  from all_objects
  where rownum < 10
)
--
SELECT pk_te.substitute('$1 ($2)', ty_p( mix_type, mix_num ) ) as description
FROM acid_batch
WHERE mix_num < 10;
```

An effective implementation with one time compilation (parsing):

```
with acid_batch as (
  select rownum as mix_type, rownum + 2 as mix_num 
  from all_objects
  where rownum < 10
),
--
o as ( 
  select ty_te.compile_numbered( '$1 ($2)' ) te from dual
)
SELECT pk_te.substitute( o.te, ty_p( mix_type, mix_num ) ) as description
FROM acid_batch, o
WHERE mix_num < 10;
```

BTW it also supports named placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

Just another idea for you: I've found REPLACE to be useful for this kind of thing, especially when the template is complex:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(
        '%mix_type% (%mix_num%)' /*template*/
       ,'%mix_type%', mix_type)
       ,'%mix_num%' , mix_num ) as description,
FROM   acid_batch
WHERE  mix_num < 10
```

The only downside is you need to add as many `REPLACE(`'s as there are variables to replace - but at least you only need to have one per variable, regardless of how many times it appears in the template.

*(NOTE: There is no particular significance to using "%" as a delimiter, it's just a personal convention of mine - you might choose a different pattern, e.g. `<mix_type>` or `[mix_type]`)*

For this particular instance it looks like overkill, but in some cases it can make things much easier, e.g.:

```
template := 'bla bla %a% %b% %a%';
output := REPLACE(REPLACE(template
    ,'%a%', some_complex_expression)
    ,'%b%', b);
```

Compare the above with:

```
output := 'bla bla ' || some_complex_expression || ' ' || b || ' ' || some_complex_expression;
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but you would probably only want to do this on a small template with few variables.  My reasoning for this is I think that REPLACE  would parse the template once fore each call, so that could eat up cpu.

Comment: If you had thousands of variables, agreed. I've used this for up to a dozen variables with no appreciable performance impact. It's not really "parsing" as such - a replace is a relatively simple string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it in the select.

```
SELECT mix_type || '(' ||  mix_num || ')' as description,
FROM acid_batch
WHERE mix_num < 10
```

you should also take a look at the functions

**[to_char](http://www.praetoriate.com/t_high_perform_conversion_functions.htm)**

**[to_date](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html)**

**[to_number](http://www.praetoriate.com/t_high_perform_conversion_functions.htm)**

as they give your a finer granularity on how you want the things represented.