# Replace special string with strings from varray plsql

Tags: plsql

I have this variables:

```
TYPE replacement IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(75);
v_names Prod_Names := Prod_Names('First','Second');
l_string   varchar2(100) := 'This is %s string with %s word.';
```

I need to replace `%s` with elements from my array. The idea is, that I will have a function which return l_string replaced with elements from varray (which will be as IN parameter).

How to do that in PL/SQL?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 'printf' equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002818/oracle-printf-equivalent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following a rather straightforward and self-docomenting code should do what you asked for. Please read the fine manual for [`regexp_replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#i1305521) parameter details. As usual the potential error scenarios are left for OP (e.g. the number of values doesn't match template string).

```
create or replace type so51_t is table of varchar2(75);
/
show errors

create or replace function so51_f(
  p_values in so51_t
 ,p_template in varchar2
) return varchar2 is
  v_ret varchar2(32767) := p_template;
begin
  for i in p_values.first .. p_values.last
  loop
    v_ret := regexp_replace(v_ret, '%s', p_values(i), 1, 1);
  end loop;
  return v_ret;
end;
/
show errors
```

**Example output**

```
select so51_f(so51_t('foo', 'bar', 'car'), '%s is %s is %s') from dual
union all
select so51_f(so51_t('foo', 'bar', 'car'), q'[I don't think this %s makes sense with %s and %s]') from dual
;

SO51_F(SO51_T('FOO','BAR','CAR'),'%SIS%SIS%S')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
foo is bar is car
I don't think this foo makes sense with bar and car
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
l_string := 'This is ' || v_names(1) ||' string with ' || v_names(2) || 'word.';
```

The double-pipes are used to concatenate strings.

Comment: No, becouse my string can be variable so i dont know where are exactly %s

Comment: Oh I totally misunderstood what you were after,

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answer myself.

Variables:

```
    l_string        VARCHAR2(500);
    l_output_string VARCHAR2(1000);
    l_temp          VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 1;
    TYPE myarray IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    TYPE t_input_params IS VARRAY(50) OF VARCHAR2(500);
    i_params        IN t_input_params,
    l_temp_array    myarray := myarray();
```

And this is body of function:

```
        FOR i IN 1..(LENGTH(l_string) - LENGTH(REPLACE(l_string, '%s', ' ')))
        LOOP
            l_temp_array.extend;
            l_temp_array(i):=INSTR(l_string,'%s',1,i);
        END LOOP;

    FOR i IN 1..least(l_temp_array.count,i_params.count)
        LOOP
            l_output_string:=l_output_string||SUBSTR(l_string,l_temp,l_temp_array(i)-l_temp)||i_params(i);
            l_temp:=l_temp_array(i)+2;
        END LOOP;   
    l_output_string:=l_output_string||SUBSTR(l_string,l_temp,length(l_string)+1-l_temp);
```