# need to replace string in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a string having `%t` at one or more places  present for `id`.

I am passing arguments to a function and it should replace the `%t` with the arguments given to function for that `id` and return replaced string.

```
function test (id in ,value1 in ,value2 in ,value 3 default null....)
```

`select test (1,sql,plsql) from dual` should return 'I am working on sql and plsql' for I am working on `%t` and `%t`.

Pseudo code (not sure if it is correct) - not sure how to replace `p||v_occur` to `p1`, `p2` ...

```
fnc_test(pid IN NUMBER,p1 IN VARCHAR2,p2 IN VARCHAR2..p5 in varchar2 default null) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
  v_out VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_occur NUMBER; 
select (length(string) - length(replace(string,'%t',null)) )/2 
  into v_occur from table where id=pid;

For i in 1..v_occur LOOP 
  v_out := v_out + v_out; 
  SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(string, 1,instr(UPPER(string),UPPER('%t'),1)+1),UPPER('%t'), p||v_occur) 
    into v_out FROM table where id=id; 

  RETURN v_out; 
END LOOP;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The algorithm seems easy enough: Find the first %t, replace it with the first replacement string. Find the next %t, replace it with the next replacement string...

Comment: We can't debug the code we cannot see.

Comment: Seems like you have dynamic input (1 to 5) and would like to return a concatenated string? Could you clarify?

Comment: @henna - Could you update to your question instead of comment. It isn't clear yet.

Comment: I think you want [Oracle 'printf' equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002818/oracle-printf-equivalent)

Comment: @VN'sCorner Right I need a  concatenated string which dynamically replaces %t by given parameter.Someone explained below but thats fixed.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I have pasted the pseudo code if it helps. Ineed to have dynamic replace the string with the number of parameters given

Comment: @psaraj12 Any solution ?

Comment: @Abra yeah but in a funciton which dynamically replaces the occruances of %t% witht the parameters given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted the solution from @Littlefoot and made it dynamic as per your requirement where in future you may add additional parameters you just need to add them in the `l_params select statement with ',' delimiter`

```
        create or replace function f_test
        (par_id in number,
       par_1 in varchar2 default null,
       par_2 in varchar2 default null,
        par_3 in varchar2 default null,
        par_4 in varchar2 default null,
        par_5 in varchar2 default null
      )
     return varchar2
      is
       l_str  varchar2(200);
       l_no_of_params number;
       l_params varchar2(32767);
     begin
      select string into l_str from dyn_table where id = par_id;

      select regexp_count(l_str, '%t') into l_no_of_params from dual;

      select par_1||','||par_2||','||par_3||','||par_4||','||par_5 into l_params from dual; 

      for i in 1 .. l_no_of_params loop
      for j in 1..l_no_of_params loop
       l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '%t', regexp_substr(l_params,'[^,]+',1,j), i, 1);
       end loop;

      end loop;
       return l_Str;
     end;
```

Use the below function for replacement of nulls

```
    create or replace function f_test
    (par_id in number,
   par_1 in varchar2 default null,
   par_2 in varchar2 default null,
    par_3 in varchar2 default null,
    par_4 in varchar2 default null,
    par_5 in varchar2 default null
  )
 return varchar2
  is
   l_str  varchar2(200);
   l_no_of_params number;
   l_params varchar2(32767);
 begin
  select string into l_str from dyn_table where id = par_id;

  select regexp_count(l_str, '%t') into l_no_of_params from dual;

  select replace(','||par_1||','||par_2||','||par_3||','||par_4||','||par_5||',',',,',',null,') into l_params from dual;

  l_params:=ltrim(rtrim(l_params,','),',');

  for i in 1 .. l_no_of_params loop
  for j in 1..l_no_of_params loop
   l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '%t', trim(regexp_substr(l_params,'[^,]+',1,j)), i, 1);
   end loop;

  end loop;
   return l_Str;
 end;
```

Comment: just one more thing if we get null as input parameter it should replace it with null.right now it is not handling that

Comment: reverted the original answer ,need further testing

Comment: yeah I checked with that only so if I pass my string as - 'country name: Values= [%t , %t, %t]' and  test1 and test2 as p1 and p2 then I am getting  final string as -----
country name: Values= [test1 , country name: Values= [test1 , test2, test1], country name: Values= [test1 , country name: Values= [test1 , test2, test1], test2]]

Comment: given one more function which handles nulls

Comment: can we show it as null where we are not passing 3rd parameter (default is null )can you plz come to chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213795/discussion-between-psaraj12-and-henna).

Answer (score 2):

As there's a limited number of `%t` strings you can have, there's no need to make it more complex than it should be - consecutive `regexp_replace` calls make it simple enough, easy to understand.

Test table first:

```
SQL> create table test (id, string) as
  2    (select 1, 'I am working on %t and %t' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Try %t next time'          from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'My %t and my %t are %t %t' from dual
  5    );

Table created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (par_id in number,
  3     par_1 in varchar2 default null,
  4     par_2 in varchar2 default null,
  5     par_3 in varchar2 default null,
  6     par_4 in varchar2 default null
  7    )
  8  return varchar2
  9  is
 10    l_str  varchar2(200);
 11  begin
 12    select string into l_str from test where id = par_id;
 13    for i in 1 .. regexp_count(l_str, '%t') loop
 14      l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '%t', par_1, 1, 1);
 15      l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '%t', par_2, 2, 1);
 16      l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '%t', par_3, 3, 1);
 17      l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, '%t', par_4, 4, 1);
 18    end loop;
 19    return l_Str;
 20  end;
 21  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test(1, 'SQL', 'PL/SQL') result             from dual union all
  2  select f_test(2, 'harder')                           from dual union all
  3  select f_test(3, 'dog', 'cat', 'complete', 'idiots') from dual;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------
I am working on SQL and PL/SQL
Try harder next time
My dog and my cat are complete idiots

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks ,its good but fixed.So what about if input parameter is not fixed ,it could vary.generic code is required where it should run to the number of times the parameters given

Comment: I have no idea what "fixed" vs. "not fixed" means.

Comment: I meant there should be no hardcoding like assuming the input values as p1...p5 ,in future may be someone can add more params to function.SO the function should run and replace '%t' the number of times as the parameeters are given

Comment: That's not what you originally asked. To remind you about what you said: `(max 5) present `. When it becomes *dynamic*, it becomes *complex*. I suggest you edit the question and specify **exactly** what you want, with examples that show *input* and desired *output*, test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements if necessary. I have difficulties in understanding *general statements and descriptions*, and certainly won't write any code based on pure guessing.

Comment: ok So I want some loop like below which replaces '%t' without giving line by line replaces-----For i in 1..v_occur LOOP 
  v_out := v_out + v_out; 
  SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(string, 1,instr(UPPER(string),UPPER('%t'),1)+1),UPPER('%t'), p||v_occur) 
    into v_out FROM table where id=id; so If I give only p1 it should execute one one time ,if I give p1 and p2 both it should execute twice. your given example is perfect but it creates single single statement . I want a single loop I know it would be complex but its requirment